# JavaScript Mootools callback

Tags: javascript, callback, mootools

How do I register my call back to formRegister in Mootools.

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Forms/Form.Validator

> // Validation.
>   new Form.Validator.Inline(myForm,{
>     formValidate:myCallback     });
>
> function myCallback(){ alert("form
>   Valid")}

Comment: do you have any code example to show?

Comment: on success I added a little example of how I though it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way of doing it. From the Mootools Demo you can do the following by attach an onSuccess callback.:

```
window.addEvent('domready', function(){

    // The elements used.
    var myForm = document.id('myForm'),
        myResult = document.id('myResult');

    // Labels over the inputs.
    myForm.getElements('[type=text], textarea').each(function(el){
        new OverText(el);
    });

    // Validation.
    new Form.Validator.Inline(myForm);

    // Ajax (integrates with the validator).
    new Form.Request(myForm, myResult, {
        requestOptions: {
            'spinnerTarget': myForm
        },
        extraData: { // This is just to make this example work.
            'html': 'Form sent.'
        },
        onSuccess: function(result){  //callback function added to demo
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I did not catch the use of the word on. Sometimes(always) I hate JS even though its so awesome.